# Which rule to enable to throw "Module has no exported member" in ESLint CLI Output?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I get a `Module "x" has no exported member "y"` in my editor (Visual Studio Code) whenever I change an exported member name while refactoring. This is very convenient as it helps me know which files have the exported member imported. But unfortunately this error shows up for only files that are currently open.

Yes I know I can rename the symbol and that should change every file that references it. But I won't be using Visual Studio Code everywhere and I don't want to rely on my IDE linter to tell me where I need to fix issues. I would like this feature enabled in the ESLint CLI output as well. Just so there is parity with what the editor shows me.

Please see this screenshot for more information on how this error looks like in VSCode:

[image: VSCode "Module Has No Exports" Error]

But when I run the eslint CLI tool on my project, from the terminal, I get no errors when it should be throwing errors for "Module has no exported members". I get errors/warnings for everything else. This leads me to believe I am missing a particular rule/setting in my `.eslintrc.js` file that enables this.

My `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
const { toPairs } = require("ramda")

const { alias } = require("./scripts/utils/getAlias")

module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true,
  },
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [".eslintrc.js"],
  plugins: ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      "error",
      { extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".md", ".mdx"] },
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        vars: "local",
        args: "none",
      },
    ],
    "import/extensions": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { devDependencies: true }],
  },
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      alias: {
        map: toPairs(alias),
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".md", ".mdx"],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

So my question is: Is this feature specific to TS Server running in VS Code or is there some setting/rule that I would need to enable in my eslintrc file so I can have parity with both terminal output and VS Code panel output?

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `import/named` rule to the .eslintrc.js file and set the value to "error":

```js
{
  rules: {
    "import/named": "error",
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea of why this isn't the default behaviour?

Comment: @AdrianDiaz No clue why this isn't the default behaviour. It should be though.